# Efficiency of an oscillating system of springs in series

Tags: energy-conservation, potential-energy, spring, efficient-energy-use

Suppose we have a system of two or more springs in series which support a mass. If the system is subject to an instantaneous longitudinal force causing the springs to oscillate, how does the efficiency of one spring affect the efficiency of the system as a whole—that is, if one spring is more or less efficient than the others?

For context, I was thinking about the mechanics of running barefoot, as opposed to wearing a pair of modern running shoes. All other things being equal, my immediate thought was that any form of footwear would simply add inefficiency to the system, being an additional medium through which energy could be absorbed. However, I then wondered whether the primary function of the footwear (in the context of energy transfer) would be to provide a space for greater elastic deformation, hence facilitating the storage of an overall greater amount of potential each landing.

Am I thinking about this the right way?